# how to preserve state using Twilio Whatsapp API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I am building a Twilio bot and I have hard time to understand how can I preserve state with each message the bot receive/send.

For example:

```
bot: "Hello"
user: "show me movies"
bot: "in what language?"
user: "english"
```

So at this point I asked the bot for two things, movies, and the language of the movies. But how I can preserve the context of the bot? i.e. "movies"? I tried to digg into [Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/learn) but there is not much information there.

My code looks like that:

```js
// whatsapp/main.js 

const accountSid = "accountSid";
const authToken = "authToken";
const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);
const MessagingResponse = require("twilio").twiml.MessagingResponse;

function sendResponse(req, res, next) {
  console.log("echo:", req.body.Body);
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message(req.body.Body);
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/xml" });
  res.end(twiml.toString());
}

module.exports = { sendMessage, sendResponse };
```

```js
// api.js

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { sendResponse } = require("../actions/whatsapp/main");

router.post("/incoming", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  sendResponse(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

So at the moment I simply echo the message the bot received. The main problem is that each message the bot receiving is a new `post` request so it's a little tricky to do what I want (or it more likely I just don't know how to do that)

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

Mostly, message hooks are stateless, and usually people persist state in their own data store. Nevertheless, what you could do is to use [cookies that will be send back and forth in a timespan of 4 hours](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/07/the-definitive-guide-to-sms-conversation-tracking.html). This way you could persist session data.

You might also want to take a look at [Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect) which allows you to collect several answers in one task using `collect`.

Hope that helps. Happy to answer further questions. :)

Edited:

Here's also [the particular part in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-create-sms-conversations-node-js).

Comment: @stefenjudis Thanks for your reply. Surely cookies will be the right solution here. But how can I set a cookie in the web hook Twilio provides? I mean I never really call it. Its just configured through the console. Am I missing something?

Comment: Twilio responds the value you set in the following calls. It's described in the article. :) You set a cookie value and it will be sent in the following webhooks. :)

Comment: where I set it though? You have any documentation about it?

Comment: You set the cookie in your express application. :) E.g. for your case you could get a hold on the send messages with a messageCount and then take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue and I just wanted to share this. Hope it helps anyone having a similar issue

I read links [@stefan judis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253183/stefan-judis) shared in this answer I found out managing the state is up to you
There is probably no wrong or right way of doing it

**Here are some suggestions for handling state with the whatsapp api**

- In my case am using caching every response from a user into memory
  and using that as my state (to keep/remember the previous response of that same user on new requests)
- I could also use a database for this purpose

Hope this is helpful and helps anyone having this same issue